# Screen artifacts on Kali linux

Tags: linux, kali-linux, laptop, firmware, amd-graphics

i installed kali linux on my laptop with ryzen 3500u and vega8 graphic card. i think it is caused by missing firmware, but i can't find all of possible missing firmware. On this laptop i have also ubuntu intalled and there problem does not exist.

```
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi12_gpu_info.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi14_gpu_info.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi10_gpu_info.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/renoir_gpu_info.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/arcturus_gpu_info.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/arcturus_asd.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/arcturus_sos.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi12_asd.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi12_sos.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi14_asd.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi14_sos.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi10_asd.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi10_sos.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/vega20_ta.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/renoir_asd.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/renoir_rlc.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/renoir_mec2.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/renoir_mec.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/renoir_me.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/renoir_pfp.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/renoir_ce.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/arcturus_rlc.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/arcturus_mec2.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/arcturus_mec.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/raven_kicker_rlc.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi12_rlc.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi12_mec2.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi12_mec.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi12_me.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi12_pfp.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi12_ce.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi14_rlc.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi14_mec2.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi14_mec.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi14_me.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi14_pfp.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi14_ce.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi14_mec2_wks.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi14_mec_wks.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi14_me_wks.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi14_pfp_wks.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi14_ce_wks.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi10_rlc.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi10_mec2.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi10_mec.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi10_me.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi10_pfp.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi10_ce.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/renoir_sdma.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/arcturus_sdma.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi12_sdma1.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi12_sdma.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi14_sdma1.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi14_sdma.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi10_sdma1.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi10_sdma.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi10_mes.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi12_vcn.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi14_vcn.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi10_vcn.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/renoir_vcn.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/arcturus_vcn.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi12_smc.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi14_smc.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/navi10_smc.bin for module amdgpu
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/amdgpu/arcturus_smc.bin for module amdgpu
```

I found modules for navi10, navi14 and renoir and put them in /lib/firmware/amdgpu, but nothing changed. I can't find anywhere files for arcturus, navi12 and vega20_ta.bin file

here is output of sudo dmesg command 
https://pastebin.com/qTKL2cbs

Answer (score 0):

try this: in menu go to settings->Window Manager Tweaks go to tab Compositor and uncheck  Enable display composing

Fixed issue for me